# Spring WS add ValueType attribute in SOAP request header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soap

I'm working in a SOAP client application using Spring Web and I need to invoke a external service which requires authentication with Binary Security Token. I have a working example from the service provider team which is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsst="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/tokentype/5.0.2" ValueType="wsst:LTPA">generated_token</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Taking [this post](https://www.devglan.com/spring-mvc/custom-header-in-spring-soap-request) as guide I wrote this callback:

```
@Component
public class CrmBinarySecurityTokenHeaderCallback implements WebServiceMessageCallback {

    @Autowired
    private TokenGenerator tokenGenerator;

    @Override
    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        String securityToken = tokenGenerator.getToken();

        try {
            SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();

            Name headerElementName = soapEnvelope.createName("Security", "wsse",
                    "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

            SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(headerElementName);
            SOAPElement securityTokenSoapElement = soapHeaderElement.addChildElement("BinarySecurityToken", "wsse");
            securityTokenSoapElement.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsst", "http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/tokentype/5.0.2");

            QName valueType = securityTokenSoapElement.createQName("ValueType", "wsst");
            securityTokenSoapElement.addAttribute(valueType, "LTPA");

            securityTokenSoapElement.addTextNode(securityToken);

            soapMessage.saveChanges();
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

and I'm getting as a result this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsst="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/tokentype/5.0.2">
             generated_token
         </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      ...
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

You can see it's almost the same except for `ValueType="wsst:LTPA"` in `<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>` element. I've been trying with some methods in `SOAPElement` API like `#addAttribute()` but wasn't able to add this `ValueType` attribute.

Any help and/or clue on how to achieve this, is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your answers/comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after checking the javax.xml.bind documentation, I got to the solution. You can use `SOAPEnvelope` object to create a `Name` and add it as attribute, like this:

```
    @Override
    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        String securityToken = tokenGenerator.getToken();

        try {
            SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();

            Name headerElementName = soapEnvelope.createName("Security", "wsse",
                    "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

            SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(headerElementName);
            SOAPElement securityTokenSoapElement = soapHeaderElement.addChildElement("BinarySecurityToken", "wsse");
            securityTokenSoapElement.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsst", "http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/tokentype/5.0.2");

            // Create ValueType name...
            Name valueTypeName = soapEnvelope.createName("ValueType");
            // ... and add it as attribute
            securityTokenSoapElement.addAttribute(valueTypeName, "wsst:LTPA");

            securityTokenSoapElement.addTextNode(securityToken);

            soapMessage.saveChanges();
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

Just for reference, the documentation I checked was:

- [Jakarta SOAP Javadoc - Package javax.xml.soap](https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.xml.soap/jakarta.xml.soap-api/1.4.2/javax/xml/soap/package-summary.html)
- [Jakarta SOAP Javadoc - Class SOAPElement](https://javadoc.io/static/jakarta.xml.soap/jakarta.xml.soap-api/1.4.2/javax/xml/soap/SOAPElement.html)
- [Jakarta SOAP Javadoc - Class Name](https://javadoc.io/static/jakarta.xml.soap/jakarta.xml.soap-api/1.4.2/javax/xml/soap/Name.html)

Hope this can help someone. Best regards